# Field and text delimiters within cells in csv files

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, streamreader, openoffice-calc

This is likely a very basic question that I could not, despite trying, find a satsifying answer to. Feel free to skip to the question at the end if you aren't interested in the background.

**The task:**

I wish to create an easy localisation solution for my unity projects. After some initial research I concluded it would be best to use a .csv file read by a streamreader, so that translators would only ever have to interact with the csv table, where information is neatly organized.

**The main problem:**

Due to the nature of the text, I need to account for linebreaks and special characters in the actual fields. As such I could not use the normal readLine() method.
This I worked with by using Read() and checking if a linebreak is within a text delimiter bracket. But as I check for the text delimiter, I am afraid it might run into an un-escaped delimiter part of the normal in-cell text (since the normal text delimiter is quotation marks).

So I switched the delimiter to §. But now every time I open the file I have to re-enter § as a text delimiter in OpenOfficeCalc, probably due to encoding differences. Which is annoying but not the end of the world.

**My question:**

How does OpenOffice (or similar software) usually tell in-cell commas/quotation marks apart from the ones used as delimiters? If I knew that, I could probably incorporate a similar approach in my reading of the file.

I've tried to look at the files with NotePad++, revealing a difference in linebreaks (/r instead of /r/n) and obviously it's within a text delimiter bracket, but when it comes to how it seperates its delimiters from ones just entered in the text/field, I am drawing a blank.

Translation file in OpenOffice Calc:

[image: Csv in Openoffice]

Translation file in NotePad++, showing all characters:

[image]

I'd appreciate any insight or links on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values:

> The CSV file format is not fully standardized. The basic idea of separating fields with a comma is clear, but that idea gets complicated when the field data may also contain commas or even embedded line breaks.

LibreOffice Calc has a reasonable way to handle these things.

- Use `LF` for line breaks and `CR` at the end of each record. It seems your code already handles this.
- Use quotes to delimit strings when needed. If the string contains one or more quotes, then duplicate the quote to make it literal.

From the example in your question, it looks like you told Calc not to use any quotes as string delimiters. Why did you do this? When I tried it, LibreOffice (or Apache OpenOffice) showed the fields in different columns after opening the file saved that way.

The following example CSV file has fields that contain commas, quotes and line breaks.
When viewed in Calc:

```
  A          B
  ---------  --
1 | 1,",2",  3
  ---------  -- 
2 | a        c
  | b
```

Calc correctly reads and saves the file as shown below. Settings when saving are *Field delimiter* `,` and *String delimiter* `"` which are the defaults.

```
"1,"",2"",",3[CR]
"a
b",c[CR]
```